# Getting Firebase Client Config key/values from within Firebase Admin backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Context:

- Backend gets firebase client config key/values (apiKey, authDomain, etc) and passes it to client
- Client uses said config to set which Firebase App it initializes into
- Node backend

I've been browsing the firebase-admin npm module and have yet to find anything that points me in the right direction. Er, actually let me correct myself, the only thing I can't seem to acquire from the backend is the apiKey and appId

Answer (score 0):

You must not pass your keys to client, they are sensitive data and must stay in your backend env, sou they are built-in when you build your application and keep safe in there.
You should make a request asking data from client to backend to get this information, and your backend will be responsible to connect with firebase, get  data and send it to frontend

client <> backend <> firebase

and not

backend <> client <> firebase

Comment: What? That's not even remotely accurate. Firebase config key/values are not sensitive by any means. Firebase's intended purpose (holistically - not in my implementation) is client <> firebase, hence why it's referred to as a backend as a service package. In my case I have 2 implementations: client <> firebase and client <> backend <> firebase. For reasons that I don't need to get into here.

Comment: @Vanessa: you might want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public as the rules around these values are somewhat different when it comes to Firebase.

Comment: Thanks Frank for the reference! I always used the keys in backend end to my informations and understand the question wrong. Thanks a lot!! And sorry for the misunderstand

Answer (score 0):

The closest API I know of are the  [`projects/get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/get) and the [`projects/getAdminSdkConfig`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/getAdminSdkConfig) in the REST API. I'm not sure if that is wrapped in the Admin SDK though, as I don't immediately see them in the most promising section of its [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/firebase-admin.project-management).

Comment: The response from projects/getAdminSdkConfig (from what I see in the docs) is acquirable directly from the Admin SDK (from what i'm testing). The only missing piece is the appId and apiKey :/